# Labelling exchange addresses in ethereum-etl datasets and BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, ethereum, blockchain, cryptocurrency

I want to query all of known CEX addresses (ideally from the beginning of ETH til now) with google bigquery.
So far, I'm getting data from the `bigquery-public-data` & `crypto-ethereum` using SQL.
If possible, I also want the list for DEX addresses.
Is there any dataset that I can extract data from?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: CEX addresses are not public information, so you cannot get them from Big Query (you can buy them privately). DEX addresses are available in [Trading Strategy Exchanges dataset](https://tradingstrategy.ai/trading-view/backtesting) which I have been owrking on.

Comment: ah i knew this, is that the `Decentralised exchanges`

Comment: Yes, that's it. You can [find the data description here](https://tradingstrategy.ai/docs/api/client/help/tradingstrategy.exchange.Exchange.html#tradingstrategy.exchange.Exchange). Note that this covers only Uniswap-like DEXes, as there are dozens of different DEX types available (although not that popular).

Comment: yes, i just converted it into the dataframe, one last questions, is the `address` field the DEX address that I want? sorry if it's a stupid question since i'm new to this crypto :(

Comment: A good question! After I wrote my last comment, I realised you probably do not know how DEXes work and have a wrong assumption about them. There is no single "deposit" address or even a single "swap address." Uniswap has multiple "router" smart contracts, but one does not need to use them. In fact, aggregators like 1inch, which is most of the volume, do not use them. Thus, for DEX, only way to analyse trades, you need to analyse each liquidity pool / pair contract individually.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Ah I see, so sorry if these were stupid questions. really appreciate all of your supports. As I knew about CEX, we can get CEX addresses on dune analytics, but there are some just appeared from 2022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @Mikko Ohtamaa, You cannot get the CEX address from BigQuery UI as they are not public information. Instead, you can buy them privately. DEX addresses are available in **[Trading Strategy Exchanges dataset](https://tradingstrategy.ai/trading-view/backtesting)**.

You can find the **[data description here](https://tradingstrategy.ai/docs/api/client/help/tradingstrategy.exchange.Exchange.html#tradingstrategy.exchange.Exchange)**. This covers only Uniswap-like DEXes, as there are dozens of different DEX types available.

Also, as mentioned by @Mikko Ohtamaa, there is no single "deposit" address or even a single "swap address." Uniswap has multiple "router" smart contracts, but one does not need to use them. In fact, aggregators like 1inch, which is most of the volume, do not use them. Thus, for DEX, the only way to analyze trades, you need to analyze each liquidity pool / pair contract individually.

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.